# Output from secret rotation in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, handler, aws-secrets-manager

I have currently set up initiating a custom function when secret rotation is called in AWS secret manager. This is sending an inputstream to the function handleRequest. However, I need the function to receive a string. Is there any way to have the rotation send a string?[image]

```
public Object handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, Context context) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if (new byte[inputStream.available()].length == 9) {
        VersionResponse versionResponse = createVersionResponse();
       return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(versionResponse);
    } else {
        carryOutRotation();
        return null;
        }
```

Comment: Where do you see an inputstream? If I'm looking at the right thing, the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-lambda-function-overview.html) suggests that the Lambda function is invoked with a JSON request comprising Step, SecretId, and ClientRequestToken.

Comment: I would have thought that too. My handlRequest in the invoked function has an inputStream as a parameter. Now I assume that a JSON coming in is converted to an inputStream as part of its journey but when I change that parameter to a String it causes an error. I have an endpoint that invokes the function as well, sending a JSON, and if the parameter is set to string that one gets the right response. However, if I set the handlRequest parameter as inputStream it then gets a null back - very frustrating!

Comment: How was your handleRequest function created? How did it come to have an inputStream parameter?

Comment: Java uploaded into the lambda as part of a LambdaHandler class.

Comment: @jarmod code is above.

Comment: But how did that source code come to be that way? Did AWS auto-generate it? Did you write it? I don't work with Java but I would expect your Java Lambda function to receive [SecretsManagerRotationEvent](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/pull/130/commits/a4edc2210df93c9551cf8aefaee247f352efb2b1). Some sample Java Lambda handlers [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps/java-events/src/main/java/example).

Comment: @HywelGriffiths [Added support for secret manager rotation event. #130](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/pull/130) seems like the support is there, check your version of the library.

Comment: You might want to also look at the [sample rotation Lambdas](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas) provide by AWS.